# Выбрать наиболее встречаемое значение по заданному ключу

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

У меня есть список словарей типа такого:

```
[{'one': 's', 'two': 'q'}, {'one': 'q', 'two': 's'}, {'one': 's', 'two': 'w'}]
```

Как мне максимально просто узнать наоболее часто встречаемое значение по некоторому ключу ? Например, по ключу `'one'` чаще всего встречается значение `'s'`. Существуют ли для этого какие-то стандартные функции или методы ?

Comment: Чем вам не угодил for?

Comment: Таки да, я бы тоже написал это с for

Comment: @insolor через него я и сам сделаю. `Python` - довольно локаничный язык. Я предположил, что в нем есть какие-то элегантные конструкции.

Comment: @faoxis, генераторные конструкции довольно элегантны, но в них есть for. Они тоже не подходят?

Comment: @insolor продемонстрируйте, пожалуйста. :)

Comment: Вообще есть некий `collections.Counter`, но как в него скормить список словарей я сходу не понял

Comment: @andreymal там вроде все просто

Comment: @faoxis с циклом for — конечно просто :)

Comment: @andreymal сделал без `for` :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы получить коллекцию значений по ключу из списка словарей:

```
values = map(itemgetter(key), list_of_dicts)
```

См. [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Чтобы найти самое частое значение:

```
[(most_common, _)] = Counter(values).most_common(1)
```

См. [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 3):

Пока придумал только такое максимально простое решение с одним `for`:

```
import collections

alist = [{'one': 's', 'two': 'q'}, {'one': 'q', 'two': 's'}, {'one': 's', 'two': 'w'}]

search_value = 'one'

cnt = collections.Counter()
for e in alist:
   cnt[e[search_value]] += 1
# cnt
# Counter({'s': 2, 'q': 1})

cnt.most_common(1)[0][0]
#'s'
```

**Update.** Нашел способ короче:

```
from collections import Counter

search_value = 'one'
alist = [{'one': 's', 'two': 'q'}, {'one': 'q', 'two': 's'}, {'one': 's', 'two': 'w'}]
print(Counter(map(lambda x: x[search_value], alist)).most_common(1)[0][0]) # 's'
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант через генератор:

```
from collections import Counter

ld = [{'one': 's', 'two': 'q'}, {'one': 'q', 'two': 's'}, {'one': 's', 'two': 'w'}]

def most_common_value(ld, key):
    return Counter(d[key] for d in ld if key in d).most_common(1)[0][0]

print(most_common_value(ld, 'one'))  # s
```